# RabbitMQ - use HTTP auth backend only for authentication?

Tags: authentication, rabbitmq

Per https://www.rabbitmq.com/access-control.html, RabbitMQ has the ability to use authentication (who is the user) and authorization (what can the user do?)

I'm using a rather obscure plugin for authorization already. I was wondering if there was a way to use the HTTP backend ONLY for authentication, because it would gel extremely well with the Django server that this project is using (users on the Django server may be allowed onto the Rabbit server).

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Never used before, but this plugin should solve:

https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-auth-backend-http

> This plugin provides the ability for your RabbitMQ server to perform
>   authentication (determining who can log in) and authorisation
>   (determining what permissions they have) by making requests to an HTTP
>   server.

Comment: I have successfully used the `rabbitmq-auth-backend-http` to allow my Django users to authenticate & authorize to RabbitMQ.